# BLE background mode in iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, background, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios8.1

I've been working on application that receives health data trough BLE. It's been working correctly in background and sending the notification when in specific conditions.
Problems, unfortunately, occured when I installed the iOS 8.1. It doesn't trigger peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic while in background. When I go with the app back to foreground - it receives data correctly.

In Info.plist -> UIBackgroundModes bluetooth-central is added.

My tests shown, that in 8.0 it was still working.

Comment: I get background notifications after updating my device to iOS 8.1. Could your issue be related to State Preservation and Restoration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created my bluetoothManager to be used within the AppDelegate.sharedInstance.

Initialisation of BLEManager was made in AppDelegate in `init` and should be done in `ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

After moving its initialization it started working. iOS behaviour is sometimes unknown. Better init your managers when app is loaded and ready to go!

Comment: WOW you saved me from a few days of banging my head! THANK YOU!! I had a static method initializing the bluetooth manager, but was too early and moved it to `ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and background mode started working. THANK YOU THANK YOU!!